# Multiple meshes with rigify: One does not transform at all

Tags: rigify

I have been experimenting with the latest rigify version where there is a horse rig added. 
The hair meshes do what they should when I go to pose mode and behave somewhat okay. 
The horse main mesh however does not. 
I have seen in weight paint mode that there have not been applied ANY weights though I selected so. Any solution to let it be re-calculated?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What method did you use to weight paint? With automatic weights on parenting?...

Comment: Correctly. I parented and selected "with automatic weights" in the options there.

Comment: Have you tried selecting a deforming pose bone(s), then go to weight paint and choose weights > Assign Automatic from bones.

Comment: Do I have to do that with every bone or just the deform bone layer with all selected?

Comment: Either way..  8^)

Comment: "Warning: Bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones" what now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that there was an issue with too many verticies in the object causing the automatic weight painting mode to not work at all. 
By doing retopology and/or simply **decreasing the face count** and repeating the steps it will work.